# fromstring() -> tostring() modifies the overall HTML structure

Tags: python, html, lxml

I am trying to use lxml.html for writing a cleanup routine to remove
empty DIV elements having no content. During the debugging I noticed that
a standard tostring() -> fromstring() iteration modifies my HTML.
Firstly it removes the outer body tag and secondly it changes the DIV structure.

Why?

```
(Pdb) from lxml.html import fromstring, tostring
(Pdb) print html

<body>
<div></div>
<p>hello world</p>
<div>   </div>
<p><div> </div></p>
</body>

(Pdb) print tostring(fromstring(html))
<div>
<div></div>
<p>hello world</p>
<div>   </div>
<p></p><div> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's correct. While your example is well-formed, it is not valid html so lxml tries to correct it to the best of its ability. In particular the div element can't be nested inside p elements and the root tag cannot be body. Use the etree module instead:

```
from lxml.etree import fromstring, tostring
```

Comment: You are right with the improper nesting of a div inside a p however I am dealing with lots of html fragments and modification of the outer tag is not an option here. Any option to suppress this modification?